# IF Condition in SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

how can i convert this code in sqlite query

```
Select *
from TABLE
where id = 1 AND
      IF(RECEIPT_MODE = 'MANUAL', DATE(a.MANUAL_COLLECTION_DATE) = DATE('2015-02-10 09:12:00'), DATE(a.TPAY_ISSUED_DATE) = DATE('2015-02-10 09:12:00'))
```

it works in my navicat but when i try these in SQLite 'IF' is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `if()`.  Just use logic:

```
select *
from TABLE
where id = 1 AND
      ( (receipt_mode = 'MANUAL' and DATE(a.MANUAL_COLLECTION_DATE) = DATE('2015-02-10 09:12:00') or
        (receipt_mode <> 'MANUAL' and DATE(a.TPAY_ISSUED_DATE) = DATE('2015-02-10 09:12:00'))
      );
```

---

EDIT:

[I am leaving this edit in the answer, although I don't agree with this approach.  Although it might be logically equivalent, I think it obfuscates the logic for most people.]

Speaking of logic, you can use the DNF to CNF rewrite rule to reduce the level of parens/nesting:

```
select *
from TABLE
where id = 1 
      AND ( receipt_mode <> 'MANUAL' OR DATE(a.MANUAL_COLLECTION_DATE) = DATE('2015-02-10 09:12:00') )
      AND ( receipt_mode =  'MANUAL' OR DATE(a.TPAY_ISSUED_DATE) = DATE('2015-02-10 09:12:00') );
```

Comment: that is the meaning of <>?

Comment: @user2930462 . . . It means "not equals" in SQL.

Comment: THIS is USEFUL thanks

Comment: "it might be logically equivalent" - it is :) Demo [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=P+AND+(+(+Q+AND+R+)+OR+(+(+NOT+Q+)+AND+S+)+)&dataset=). "obfuscates": All logical differences are big differences; all non-logical differences are small differences. P.S. good sport for leaving the edit in :)